# Tailwind - Override default transition duration

Tags: tailwind-css

Default is 150ms, was looking to extend this to 250ms as an application default.

Tried everything I could think of, last attempt being

```
transitionDuration: {
   DEFAULT: '250ms'
},
```

in `tailwind.config.js` under `theme`, `theme.extend`, `variants`, and `variants.extend`.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: theme.extend is ok. you probably just not recompiled changes

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```json
theme: {
   transitionDuration: {
      DEFAULT: '250ms'
    }
}
```

in your `tailwind.config.js` should work.

Demo: https://play.tailwindcss.com/zSWIMghZQf
(Default transition duration overwritten to 2000ms.)

For reference: With `npx tailwindcss init --full` you can create a configuration file that contains all tailwind default values.

Comment: I am super confused as that's exactly what I had, but it does work now. I'm doing it in Angular and maybe was an issue with the new JIT compiler. After restarting the local dev server, it has picked it up.

Answer (score 2):

Just like ptts answered before me, inserting an override in the `theme` section of your `tailwind.config.js` will do the trick.

What I'd like to add is that the new value for `transitionDuration` [will completely replace Tailwind’s default configuration for that key](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/theme#overriding-the-default-theme), and the initial transition duration utilities will not be generated. So if you only define `DEFAULT` under the `transitionDuration` key, your classes like `.duration-500` will not work.

The solution is to define the full set of duration values you might use. For your convenience, here's the full set from [the default theme](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/blob/master/stubs/defaultConfig.stub.js):

```
transitionDuration: {
  DEFAULT: '150ms',
  75: '75ms',
  100: '100ms',
  150: '150ms',
  200: '200ms',
  300: '300ms',
  500: '500ms',
  700: '700ms',
  1000: '1000ms',
},
```

If you want to update the `DEFAULT` while still retaining all of the other durations, use something like:

```
transitionDuration: {
  DEFAULT: '500ms',
  75: '75ms',
  100: '100ms',
  150: '150ms',
  200: '200ms',
  300: '300ms',
  500: '500ms',
  700: '700ms',
  1000: '1000ms',
},
```

Comment: You could add the value to `theme.extend.transitionDuration.DEFAULT`. It will leave the default theme intact and only replace the default value. Can also add to them as I have with `slow` and `fast` for some 'aliased standards' for your application.

Comment: Have you tried adding to `theme.extend` and verified that it works? I had tried it before and it didn't work, but perhaps I was doing something else wrong...

Comment: Yup, I add a few to extends and it keeps the original built-ins. My issue originally was an early version of the JIT compiler and caching - it seems if you added it to the theme (not extend), it would override, but if you then moved it to extend, the compiled output would be cached, leaving the built-ins wiped out. At least at the time, I had to delete `.angular` directory to remove the cache. Don't know if it's still an issue.